# ng-bind-html with angular-translate renders text instead of HTML tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, ng-bind-html

I'm back on an old AngularJS project (1.7.2) with angular-translate and I'm struggling with `ng-bind-html`.

In my HTML I wrote this

```
<span ng-bind-html="'LEFT_PANEL.VISITED_AFTER' | translate"></span>
```

The result I'm expecting is

```
<span>Visited <strong>after</strong> this date. </span>
```

What I have in my translation file is:

```
"VISITED_AFTER": "Visited <strong>after</strong> this date"
```

What I actually get is:

```
<span ng-bind-html="'LEFT_PANEL.VISITED_BEFORE' | translate" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
Visited &lt;strong&gt;before&lt;/strong&gt; this date
</span>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

(yes I have `ngSanitize` in my modules)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NgTranslate is using it's own Sanitizer ([Docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security))

To change the sanitize strategy globally use `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy("STRATEGY");`
If you only want to have a different strategy for this element use the attribute `translate-sanitize-strategy`

Comment: you're right! I was using the 'escape' strategy. Moving to 'sce' worked.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586588/ng-bind-html-or-ngsanitize-not-working).

Seems to have to do with HTML decoding.
Add this function:

```
function decodeHtml(html) {
  var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
  txt.innerHTML = html;
  return txt.value;
}
```

And surround what you're printing with: `decodeHtml(...)`

Actually just look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gpIPCqQ7FTMv4scH1xll?p=preview)

Comment: the `decodeHtml` function does not seem to be part of Angular, and manipulates the DOM directly which I'd like to avoid

Comment: Check out edited answer, just look at the plunkr. Should be able to figure it out from there.